# Cambridge Mathematical Tripos papers from late 19th century

Tags: ho.history-overview, mathematics-education

Are the scanned images of Cambridge Mathematical Tripos papers from late 19th century available anywhere on Internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [collection](https://archive.org/details/mathematicalprob00wolsrich), with solutions, from the period 1864-1878 (published by Joseph Wolstenholme). An earlier period, 1800-1820, was collected by [I.M.F. Wright.](https://books.google.nl/books?id=KBtRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR6&lpg=PR6&dq=wright+tripos+problems+cambridge&source=bl&ots=q43kp2QPwr&sig=K9vI6WDS29xFu4FQgDV4YfxmGYA&hl=nl&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

These are transcriptions of the problem sets, not copies of the original documents, some of which you can find [here (1913-1917)](https://archive.org/details/papersetinmathtr00cambrich) (freely accessible) and [here (1908-1912)](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b2825298) (only accessible in the US because of copyright restrictions).

Comment: Doesn't copyright usually expire 70-100 years after the death of the original author (depending on country)?

Comment: @StefanKohl --- true, I have added a link that explicitly says "not in copyright", and another that says "public domain in the US"